# Cannot run xmlParse()

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to read an `xml` file using the function `xmlParse()` on `rstudio`. I have installed and loaded (globally) all the packages required for this, namely `XML` and `methods`. Here is my code:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/R ")
xmlParse(file = "input.xml")
```

I set the directory where the file `input.xml` is located. The information in the file looks like this:

```
<RECORDS>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <NAME>Rick</NAME>
    <SALARY>623.3</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>1/1/2012</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>IT</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <NAME>Dan</NAME>
    <SALARY>515.2</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>9/23/2013</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>Operations</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <NAME>Michelle</NAME>
    <SALARY>611</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>11/15/2014</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>IT</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <NAME>Ryan</NAME>
    <SALARY>729</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>5/11/2014</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>HR</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <NAME>Gary</NAME>
    <SALARY>843.25</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>3/27/2015</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>Finance</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>6</ID>
    <NAME>Nina</NAME>
    <SALARY>578</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>5/21/2013</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>IT</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>7</ID>
    <NAME>Simon</NAME>
    <SALARY>632.8</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>7/30/2013</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>Operations</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <ID>8</ID>
    <NAME>Guru</NAME>
    <SALARY>722.5</SALARY>
    <STARTDATE>6/17/2014</STARTDATE>
    <DEPT>Finance</DEPT>
  </EMPLOYEE>
</RECORDS>
```

The ouput from the code is supposed to look like this:

```
1
Rick
623.3
1/1/2012
IT


2
Dan
515.2
9/23/2013
Operations


3
Michelle
611
11/15/2014
IT


4
Ryan
729
5/11/2014
HR


5
Gary
843.25
3/27/2015
Finance


6
Nina
578
5/21/2013
IT


7
Simon
632.8
7/30/2013
Operations

Howe

8
Guru
722.5
6/17/2014
Finance
```

However, I am getting an unprocessed data (like it originally was). I don't know what to do.

I have tried different ways of creating the `xml` file. I used MS word, a python editor, textEdit and a mac Notepad. I pasted the `xml` formatted text on each of these and saved with the extension `.xml`. I don't know what else to do. Some guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: you have not provided code to reproduce your issue and it seems you haven't read the documentation about what `xmlParse()` actually returns and the difference between data structures and printed object output. You should likely spend some more time learning about R and reading the docs for the `XML` package.

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. Do you want a list? Dataframe? `xmlParse` simple parses file into memory for later use, not designed to build structures. Please edit post with more info.

Comment: @Parfait. Thank you! Let me read more on this.